# setInterval js does not update result

Tags: javascript, php

I have my countdown function (that works).

```
      // Set the date we're counting down to
      var countDownDate = new Date("<?= $stop_datejs ?>");

      // Update the count down every 1 second
      var x = setInterval(function() {

          // Get todays date and time
          var now = new Date();

          // Find the distance between now an the count down date
          var distance = countDownDate - now;

          // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
          var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
          var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
          var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
          var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

          // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
          + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

          // If the count down is over, write some text
          if (distance < 0) {
              clearInterval(x);
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ACTUALIZA LA PÁGINA";
          }
      }, 1000);
```

But I need to compare with a php variable $actual_date (server date)

```
          // Get todays date and time
          var now = new Date("<?= $actual_date ?>");
```

That works but stops updating every second. What is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: You can only communicate with the server by form submission or an AJAX request. It doesn't interact in any way with your PHP code.

Comment: The script works if you replace the variable `var countDownDate = new Date("2017/08/08");` . Try printing `<?= date("yyyy/mm/dd") ?>`. Quite likely the server date format issue.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `now` will not be updated, because the variable will only be *written* once. So if you load the the webpage the value will be set once but not updated, because the website does not update again (Only your interval).
To provide this you can simply use:

```
// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date();
```

This will only use the **current time** for the new instance of `Date`. If your `<?= $actual_date ?>` is not the current timestamp or you want to sync if for all browsers/pc with an incorrect time setting you should have a look at `AJAX`. Using AJAX is the easiest way to get the updated time from the backend.

jQuery Ajax:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The code works using var now = new Date ();
But I need to compare a current date with a countdown end date (stored in the database)
And insert a record every 24 hours for users from different countries.

Comment: The best and easiest solution for that is using AJAX. Just have a look at the link in the answer. Therefor you should add a new api end point to your backend to get the countdown date and one  to inserting the record every 24 hours.